# One mySQL database is very slow while others are fine

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database that is currently running very slow. There are a number of databases on the server, and all other databases are running fine, however this one database is very slow, often taking between 2-10 seconds for a very simple update (updating 1 row in a small table) or select query (selecting 1 row from a small table).

My question is to ask if anyone could think of a reason why this one database is running so slow. The traffic is minimal (it is the database for the development site). I have ruled out my scripts, as phpMyAdmin is also very slow and often times out with this database. I have also checked the running processes to check nothing untoward is there, and there can be no processes ongoing, but still the database will be running really slowly.

So please can anyone shed some light on what may be happening here. I am very happy to give extra information if you require it.

EDIT:

Further to the comments, here is an example of a slow running query:

```
UPDATE `Users` SET `last active` = 1334763602 WHERE `ID` = 1
```

This simple update query is taking between 2 and 10 seconds to complete. ID is a primary key and this table has around 30 records.

Further to my initial problem, it does seem as if SELECT is not as bad, though I have seen slow periods for SELECT, a lot of SELECT statements currently are running fast, whereas UPDATE is still slow.

EDIT 2:

After more investigation it appears it might be tied to the InnoDB table type. I have changed a table to MyISAM and a query that was taking 1.5 seconds in InnoDB took just 0.0006 seconds in MyISAM. I guess my question becomes how do I best tune to InnoDB tables?

Comment: You will need to provide specific information regarding the queries that are running slow, the table designs, some query profiles (using `EXPLAIN` etc), to be able to get any particularly specific response.

Comment: Are all the database schemas the same in terms of tables and amount of records? Are there indexes created for the tables? Have you tried rebuilding indexes with optimize table?

Comment: The databases are varying sizes, and the one that is slow is certainly the largest. There is another database which is similar but smaller (the live version of this development database, the development database has been added to). There are indexes across most tables (if not all), though I have not tried recreating them.

Comment: @Simonatmso.net I have added some information about a single UPDATE statement that is running very slow, though obviously I can't EXPLAIN this as it isn't a SELECT statement. I will try and find a good example of a SELECT statement that is slow and EXPLAIN that.

Comment: While having an index on a table will speed up `SELECT` queries, it will slow down `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries. The larger the table and the more indexes on the table, the more you will notice the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries slowing down.

Comment: It looks like the issue was to do with the database setup and the InnoDB tables. When the database was using MyISAM it worked fine, so we investigated this and it turns out the default buffer pool size was too small, causing memory issues. Having upped the value for the default buffer pool size, the database is performing much faster, (probably in the region of 1000 times faster if not more). (I will post this as an answer when I can)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue was to do with the database setup and the InnoDB tables. When the database was using MyISAM it worked fine, so we investigated this and it turns out the default buffer pool size was too small, causing memory issues. Having upped the value for the default buffer pool size, the database is performing much faster, (probably in the region of 1000 times faster if not more).